# Non-root access to a wifi adapter via ioctl in Linux app - how to grant?

Tags: linux, permissions, wifi, ioctl

I'm trying to debug a Qt5 c app in Ubuntu 20.04 on Odroid board. The app communicates with wifi adapter via ioctl(), eg:

```
int fd = iw_sockets_open();
struct ifreq ifreq;
//ifreq.ifr_name holds "wlxe894f617ebe6" from "iw dev" output
if (ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifreq) == -1) {
  return FALSE;
}
```

The problem is that it works only when run as sudo. When I run it from QtCreator, it fails at above ioctl() call returning -1, perror() saying "Operation not permitted". From under sudo it passes and works furhter normally.

lsusb names adapter as:

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 148f:5572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5572 Wireless Adapter
```

iw dev gives:

```
phy#0
        Interface wlxe894f617ebe6
                ifindex 3
                wdev 0x1
                addr e8:94:f6:17:eb:e6
                type managed
                txpower 20.00 dBm
```

Also, the adapter seems to have no corresponding file in the /dev/ directory. How to grant user access to ioctl() in this case?

I tried to grant the access like with other usb devices, adding the line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="148f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5572", MODE="0666"
```

to /etc/udev/rules.d/50-myusb.rules, but with no result. I thought I should add the user to some group like "wlan" or alike, but can't find any group name which could be related here.

Comment: That's strange SIOCGIFFLAGS doesn't look to be privileged. Maybe an other mechanism (such as AppArmor) prevents it to work correctly? doing strace on /sbin/ifconfig (an other obsolete-on-Linux tool using this obsolete API) works without privilege. Are you sure it doesn't fail elsewhere, eg on a SIOCSIFFLAGS (S as set rather than G as get)?

Comment: FWIW,  [`netdevice(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html) which documents this ioctl ("Setting the active flag word is a privileged operation, but **any process may read it.**") should be avoided in favor of   [`rtnetlink(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html)  even if it's more complex and probably relies on middle libraries to be handled.

Comment: @A.B Sorry, you are right, I mixed the calls, they go toghether, it's on ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifreq) call which goes right after first one. Will correct the text.

Comment: In addition there's no debug to do anymore. That's normal it's permission denied. Better explain what you want to achieve to avoid an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) .

Comment: This is some legacy program which uses libpcap to monitor the wifi packets, I need to make some modifications to it. I read that to force QtCreator to run debuggee as root is a problem, it's why I'm looking for a way to do it. Actually I'm not much into Linux access control structure, rather at the beginner level.